# Python: loop and edit string character

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I'm new to python and coding in general. Here is a problem from my homework, as well as my current code. I know that I only have one of the parts, but I wanted to figure this one out before moving on to the rest. With my loop, I can find and identify the letter i, but I can't figure out how to change the i's to 1's.

Problem:

> Many user-created passwords are simple and easy to guess. Write a
> program that takes a simple password and makes it stronger by
> replacing characters using the key below, and by appending "!" to the
> end of the input string.
>
> ```
> i becomes 1
> a becomes @
> m becomes M
> B becomes 8
> s becomes $
> ```
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> mypassword
> ```
>
> the output is:
>
> ```
> Myp@$$word!
> ```
>
> Hint: Python strings are immutable, but support string concatenation.
> Store and build the stronger password in the given password variable.

Code:

```
word = input()
password = ()


for letter in word:
    if letter == 'i':
        password = password+'1'
    else: password = password+letter

print(password)
```

input: igigigig
output: igigigig

Comment: change password = () to password = ' '

Comment: Your code has an error, the password should be initialized with an empty string `""`. Also [this](https://onlinegdb.com/YytA6_na-) should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're initializing your password to an incorrect variable choice. `password = ()` sets password to a tuple. Attempting to add characters to a tuple variable will lead to an exception:

```
>>> password = ()
>>> password = password + '1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Next, you have a mapping of characters provided in the question. You can start by creating a dictionary to represent this mapping.

```
mapping = {
    'i': '1',
    'a': '@',
    'm': 'M',
    'B': '8',
    's': '$',
}
```

When looping against letters you can use the mapping to determine if a replacement should be made:

```
for letter in word:
    if letter in mapping:
        password = password + mapping.get(letter)
    else:
        password = password + letter
```

You also forgot to add the `!` to the end.

Final result:

```
mapping = {
    'i': '1',
    'a': '@',
    'm': 'M',
    'B': '8',
    's': '$',
}

word = "mypassword"
password = ""

for letter in word:
    if letter in mapping:
        password = password + mapping[letter]
    else:
        password = password + letter
password += "!"

print(password)
```

Simplifying this further:

```
for letter in word:
    password += mapping.get(letter, letter)
password += "!"
```

Even further with a comprehension!:

```
password = ''.join(mapping.get(l, l) for l in word) + "!"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! we haven't learned mappings yet, but i'll have to take a look at them. they seem very useful!

Answer (score 0):

you can flow the step below

- 1.Change str(word) to list off str(letter)
- 2.Use loop check and change str(letter) in list one by one
- 3.Merge list off str(letter) to str(word)

Code :

```
word = list(word)

for position in range(len(word)):
    letter = word[position]
    if letter == 'i':
        word[position] = '1'

''.join(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of some of these comments and re-reading the instructions, I was able to find the right answer that the book was looking for.

```
word = input()
password=''


for letter in word:
    if letter == 'i':
        str1 = '1'
        password = password+str1
    else: password = password+letter

print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to loop, just do `translate`:

```
pswd = 'mypassword'
pswd = pswd.translate(str.maketrans('iamBs','1@M8$'))+'!'

print(pswd) # Myp@$$word!
```